# NodeJS streaming working locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am collecting a streaming response and sending it to the frontend. Everything, including the streaming, is working properly on localhost. However, on the server, the backend is piling up all events before sending them to the frontend together. It's even waiting for the reader.on('end') event. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const response = getStreamingResponse()

    const sseStream = new SseStream(req);
    sseStream.pipe(res);

    const reader = response.body;
    let answer = "";

    reader.on('data', (data: any) => {
      let decoded = new TextDecoder().decode(data);
      answer += decoded

      sseStream.write({ data });
    });

  reader.on('end', async () => {
      console.log("End of stream");


//I have other fns like saving to Database here and then 

  const buffer = Buffer.from(savedConversation?._id, "utf-8");
  res.write(`conversationId: ${buffer.toString()}\n\n`);
  sseStream.end();

}
```

Comment: Could be that it waits to fill the buffer before actually sending the data to the frontend. Have you tried forcing it out of the buffer manually?

Comment: The issue caused, due to Nginx. So check it.